# Display result of custom directive from one element in another HTML element

Tags: angular

I'd like to display the output message from a custom validation directive into another HTML element on my form. How do I capture/refer to the output from the custom directive (`no-special-chars.directive.ts`)?

Directive (`no-special-chars.directive.ts`)

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, 
        FormControl, 
        NG_VALIDATORS, 
        ValidationErrors} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNoSpecialChars]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NoSpecialCharsDirective, multi: true}],
  exportAs: 'noSpecChars'
})
export class NoSpecialCharsDirective implements Validator{

  constructor() { }
  validate(c: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
    //console.log("input value: " + c.value);
    const hasSpecialChars = /[~!@#\^&*+=\-\[\]\';,/{}|\":<>\?\\()]/.test(c.value);
    const message = {
      'hasSpecialChars' : {
        'message': 'No Special Chars Allowed'
      }
    };
    return hasSpecialChars ? message : null;
  }
}
```

Here is the template: (git-search.component.html)

```
<h3>{{title}} - {{displayQuery}} -- (version: Template Driven)</h3>
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendQuery()">
  <div *ngFor="let key of modelKeys">
      {{key}} 
      <input  #myInput name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" required *ngIf="key==='q'" appNoSpecialChars/>
      <input  #myInput name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" minlength = '2' maxlength='4' *ngIf="key==='stars'" appNoSpecialChars />      
      <input  #myInput name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" *ngIf="key!=='q' && key!=='stars'" appNoSpecialChars/> 
      <!-- WANT TO DISPLAY MESSAGE FROM THE appNoSpecialChars DIRECTIVE INTO INNER HTML OF <p> ELEMENT BELOW: -->
      <p>MESSAGE TEXT FROM DIRECTIVE</p> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access form validation errors like that:

### git-search.component.html

```
....
<input #myInput="ngModel" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" required *ngIf="key==='q'" appNoSpecialChars/>
....
<p>MESSAGE TEXT FROM DIRECTIVE: {{myInput.errors.hasSpecialChars?.message}}</p>
....
```

So you need to get a reference to `ngModel` of form, in that case we store it in`myInput` variable, and validator will just add your special error to `errors` field of this object.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your directive could set the message in a shared service and then you could access the message from any component.